# Should I include the Default & Intranet zones url inside my search service crawl urls

Tags: 2013, search, alternate-access-mapping, content-search-web-part, web-application-zones

I have the following alternate access mapping & zone settings for our SharePoint 2013  web application, :-

[image]

So mainly we can access our web application using both:-

- Default zone using this url `http://sps01/`
- Intranet zone using this url `http://www.OurComanyName.intra`

Also inside our search service both urls are defined inside the crawling URL , as follow:-

[image]

Now I faced this problem inside my content search webparts, which I am not sure if it is related to the face that I am crawling 2 urls for my web application (default & intranet zones), the problem description is as follow:-

1. I added a new content search web part inside my site collection home page.
2. The content search web part will show all the items from all the site collections, which have their `status<>closed`
3. Now when I access the web part from the default zone `http;//sps01/` I found duplicate items being shown. one occurrence for the item will have the default zone url inside it, while the other occurrence for the same item will have the intranet zone url inside it.
4. But if I access the web part from the intranet zone, only items with the Intranet zone url will be shown (no duplicates), but the number of results inside the CSWP will be wrong. I mean by the number of results is that I define to show 10 items per page , but I will get only 5 items per page.so seems the search will return duplicate but the webpart for a reason or another will only show the items with the intranet zone URL.

So can anyone advice, if I need to define both urls for the web application inside the search service? 
If the answer is Yes then is this the reason I am getting duplicate results inside the content search web part. baring in mind that  if I use the search box I will not get any duplicates, unlike what I get inside the content search web part.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the default zone in the Content Source. Queries executed from other zones will return results mapped to the source in the same zone (unless it's missing in which case it will fail back to the default zone).

Comment: thx. So you mean i only need to add the default zone url inside the content source, and the search result will be relative to the zone which the user is browsing. so if i user is accessing the WebApplication from the default zone url, then the search results will have the default zone url, while if he access the web application from the Intranet zone, then he will get the same results but the result will have the Intranet zone is this what you  mean? second question i did not understand your exact meaning in  "_unless it's missing in which case it will fail back to the default zone _"

Comment: Correct, it will return from the current zone. If you have multiple web applications you could have zones missing in which case the default zone would be returned.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I added both urls to my content source and later removed it,  now i only get search result when i access my application with default public url.  Is there a way of resetting it back to normal.

Comment: If you have the AAMs set up correctly, you only need the default zone. What do you mean "your application"? Are you talking about a Web Application or an Add-On?